# Macbook Pro Retina Photoshop Pixelated Results?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mac, pixel, retina

I'm a web designer, and my old (non retina) Macbook, Photoshop used to produce clear images and text both in Photoshop and out of Photoshop when the final images had been saved as a png or jpg.

However, ever since moving to the retina MacBook i've been completely stumped by the fact that my text and everything else in the images are coming out pixellated, which doesn't help at all.

So, for example i'm creating a logo which is just text in a font, i'm editing at 200% which is the real size of the image i believe for the Macbook retina, the text appears blurry or pixelated and I can never seem to get it to sharpen up? This is not a case of changing the text to sharp/smooth etc because even then no matter what I choose the text is still pixellated. So when I go to save the image as a png or jpg the image, of course is still pixellated. The issue is it's not like it can go unnoticed either, it's that bad.

Am I missing some settings here? Surely graphic designers aren't putting up with this?

Sorry if this seems like a really stupid question, but I really can't get this working, so if anyone can help then it'd be really appreciated!

Comment: It's also worth noting that there is no difference in result when running Photoshop in low resolution mode. I am running Photoshop CC.

Comment: When you say editing at 200% how did you get to 200%? If you doubled the size of a raster image than that's your issue.

Comment: @Ryan Editing at 200% zoom shows me the exact size of the image and what it will look like when I save it as an image. The result is blurry, even though the image is at its actual size at 200%? I don't get it.

Comment: You should not "edit at 200%" you should create the image at twice the necessary size and edit at 100%. Retina images are double the size, not zoomed in 200%. When you edit a double-sized image at 100%, then save for non-retina screens (50%) the image will be sharper. If you are looking for pixel accuracy, then you need 2 images each @ size, not using zoom. Retina screens do not use zoom.

Comment: @Scott What would the result of this be for non retina users? Double the size images?

Comment: Problem solved, many thanks for everyones help! I did what Scott suggested and edited at 100%, and then when using images in web design, I simply reduce the size by 50% on the width and height variables. Problem solved, sharp images at last!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem however, it is when I open files via CS6. I've never had this issue before but suddenly everything I'm working on comes up as very low resolution, pixelated text and graphics. I don't believe I've changed anything in the program. I don't want to jump to assumptions, but I recently was having internet bugs, which I hope doesn't mean a bigger problem. I use all Adobe products almost daily and have never run into this issue. Even pulling layers in, it goes from decent resolution to low. On one project, I was able to adjust the image resolution size but the text still

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The confusion begins when you think you need to adjust how you work simply because you are working on a retina display. You do not. Treat your machine as you always have. Don't adjust your workflow due to the hardware you are using. Basically forget you are *working* on a retina display.

Now, to support retina display in projects, you need 2 images - one standard and one double-sized (@2) for anyone else using a retina system. To this end, I find it's always best to start with the large image, the double-sized version.

So, if you are designing a web site and need a 500x100px header image, you start with a 1000x200px image and design the header. When you are done, you can *reduce the image by 50%* to get the 500x100px image and save that. If, after reduction, there are detail areas which need adjusting, you can do that before saving. By starting with the @2x image you design for retina viewing. Reducing 50% then designs for all non-retina displays.

Retina technology doesn't use any zoom to alter image appearances. It actually swaps images. If you have images with @2x titles, even in a web site design, retina displays pull those larger images and use those, they do not simply enlarge (or zoom) the standard image 200%.

Comment: the @2x is 'automatic' only in apps. On a web site, one needs to set up their CSS accordingly to handle them. If the image is 'normal', the browser *does* double the pixels as best as it can (albeit leaving it the same 'physical' size compared to a non-retina screen)